# Why can't Rust see that the trait bound is satisfied?

Tags: rust, traits

Extract from my code:

```rust
use csv::Reader;
use rand::seq::index::{IndexVecIntoIter,sample};
use rand::thread_rng;

pub struct SamplingIter<I: ExactSizeIterator<Item = T>, T> {
    iter: I,
    indices: IndexVecIntoIter,
}

pub trait SamplingIterator: ExactSizeIterator + Sized {

    fn sample(self, amount: usize) -> SamplingIter<Self, Self::Item> {
        let len = self.len();
        SamplingIter {iter: self, indices: sample(&mut thread_rng(), len, amount).into_iter()}
    }

}
impl<I: ExactSizeIterator + Sized> SamplingIterator for I {}

impl<I: ExactSizeIterator<Item = T>, T> Iterator for SamplingIter<I, T>{
    type Item = T;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        todo!();
    }
}

pub fn example() {
    let mut rdr = Reader::from_path("foo.csv").unwrap();

    rdr.byte_records().sample(5);
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "trait-issue"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
csv = "1.2"
rand = "0.8.5"
```

Error message:

```
    Checking trait-issue v0.1.0 (/Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Rust/trait-issue)
error[E0599]: the method `sample` exists for struct `ByteRecordsIter<'_, File>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
    --> src/lib.rs:30:24
     |
30   |     rdr.byte_records().sample(5);
     |                        ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `ByteRecordsIter<'_, File>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
     |
    ::: /Users/camdennarzt/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/csv-1.2.2/src/reader.rs:2130:1
     |
2130 | pub struct ByteRecordsIter<'r, R: 'r> {
     | -------------------------------------
     | |
     | doesn't satisfy `ByteRecordsIter<'_, File>: ExactSizeIterator`
     | doesn't satisfy `ByteRecordsIter<'_, File>: SamplingIterator`
     |
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `&ByteRecordsIter<'_, File>: ExactSizeIterator`
      `&mut ByteRecordsIter<'_, File>: ExactSizeIterator`
      `ByteRecordsIter<'_, File>: ExactSizeIterator`
    --> src/lib.rs:18:9
     |
18   | impl<I: ExactSizeIterator + Sized> SamplingIterator for I {}
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ----------------     -
     |         |
     |         unsatisfied trait bound introduced here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `trait-issue` (lib) due to previous error
```

I *think* it's saying that rustc doesn't think that `ByteRecordsIter` implements `ExactSizeIterator` but it does according to [the docs](https://docs.rs/csv/latest/csv/struct.ByteRecordIter.html#impl-ExactSizeIterator-for-ByteRecordIter%3C%27r%3E). But it could be complaining about one of the other bounds it mentions, the error isn't super clear.

So what does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong struct — you want the docs for [`ByteRecordsIter`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.2.0/csv/struct.ByteRecordsIter.html), not [`ByteRecordIter`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.2.0/csv/struct.ByteRecordIter.html) (note the `s`!).

Presumably, `ByteRecordsIter` is not `ExactSizeIterator` because it doesn't know its length (roughly, the number of lines in the file), while `ByteRecordIter` is because it *does* know the number of columns.

You probably need to read the rows of the file into some long-lived, fully-in-memory data structure like a `Vec<ByteRecord>` with `let records = rdr.byte_records().collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>().unwrap();` before sampling.